# Regex to extract from square brackets?

Tags: c#, regex, jmeter

I have data made up of values inside multiple square brackets that looks like this:

```
name [Tom] state [NewYork] phone [5555]
```

I want to extract the state. This is the regex I'm using, but it is coming back blank.

```
Regex: state \[(.+?)\]
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
```

I can't see where there is a mistake in this?

Comment: Is the space a normal space? Try `\s+` instead of the literal space.

Comment: I would recommend to use `state \[(\w+)\]` since it's more relevant to your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
state\s*\[([^]]+)\]
```

Have a look at the [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/vM4gC9/2)

Comment: If `state \[(.+?)\]` does not work ([that also works at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lX0aO2/1)), why do you think your pattern will work?

Comment: well because it should. doesn't it?

Comment: may be there is a problem with the white spaces. try the edited answer.

Comment: Regex101 regex flavors do not support the JMeter regex flavor, they are only similar to it.